# PHP MySQL comparing two tables and getting values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one is called contacts and the other one is called numbers. One stores contact information and looks like this

```
contacts
-------------------------------------------------------
| id | fname | lname | email | address | uid | uniqid |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

My second table which stores phone numbers that belong to specific contact look like this

```
numbers
---------------------
| id | number | cid |
---------------------
```

The cid is the same as the uniqid on contact table, how can i get the contact row with its numbers which is on the second table through mysql?

**Update**
Correction to the correct answer

```
SELECT id ,fname ,lname ,email ,address , uid, uniqid,number
FROM contacts a
inner join (SELECT cid, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT number SEPARATOR ',') number FROM numbers) b ON b.cid=a.uniqid
```

It was missing DISTINCT

Comment: Show us sample data for both tables, and also the expected result. All as formatted text, not images!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get multiple numbers to one row and then when you imply the join you won't get duplicates.

```
select `id` ,`fname` ,`lname` ,`email` ,`address` , `uid`, `uniqid`,`number`
from `contacts` a
inner join (Select `cid`, GROUP_CONCAT(`number` seperator ',') `number` from `numbers`) b on b.cid=a.uniqid
```

Comment: Not working for some reason, i tried to capitalize the syntax. but nothing

Comment: could you be able to try now, I think it's because number is a keyword so enclose it and execute.

Answer (score 2):

use join

```
select id ,fname ,lname ,email ,address , uid, uniqid,number
from contacts a
inner join numbers b on b.cid=a.uniqid
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for help, but unfortunately it creates another row if theres another number with the same uniqid

Answer (score 1):

You can map the two id's make sure you have this as table index, for faster retrieval of data.

```
SELECT id ,fname ,lname ,email ,address , uid, uniqid, number from contacts a, number b WHERE a.uniqid = b.cid;
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Just use inner join with n.cid = c.uniqid

```
select c.id,c.fname,c.lname,c.email,c.address,c.uid,c.uniqid,n.number 
from contacts c 
inner join numbers n 
on n.cid = c.uniqid
```

Answer (score 1):

using join is the right choice here:

```
  SELECT con.*,num.* from contacts as con inner join numbers as num on con.uniqid = num.cid
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we are using the concept of `foreign key` . Here `cid` is `foreign key` of contact table on number table. we have to match `primary key` of `contact` table with the foreign key of number table. if both are match then it's show the result.

```
Select a.id, a.fname, a.lname, a.email, a.address, 
a.uid, a.uniqid,b.number from contact a, number b where a.id=b.id;
```